# Search a term in a dataframe and return a value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df like this :

```
word;Positive-Polarity;Negative-Polarity
un dos;0;0
abaque;0;0
abandonner;0;1
abandonné;0;1
abandon;0;1
se calmer;0;0
...
```

I am trying to do a function which take a input a word and returns a value of polarity (either Positive-Polarity or Negative-Polarity).

Can you help me to do this in R please?

Comment: What is polarity?

Comment: Thank you Sotos for your quick reply, I edit my question to be more explicit

Comment: Study `help("[")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to **melt** your data.frame. I use the one from data.table, but you could also use reshape2.

```
df <- data.frame(word = c("a", "b", "c"), pos = c(0,0,1), neg = c(0, 1, 0))

library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(df)
dt <- melt(df, id.vars = "word")
```

Then getting the values is as simple as:

```
dt[word == "b" & value > 0, variable]
```

We restrict to value > 0, because then we will either get Positive-Polarity or Negative-Polarity, or nothing at all, if both were 0.

Comment: thank you for your response, variable in "dt[word == "b" & value > 0, variable]" corresponds to what sorry?

Comment: word == "b" will select the word with value "b". E.g. abaque from your data.frame. value and variable were introduced by the melt function. This basically collapses the positive-polarity and negative-polarity columns into two columns, the variable column specifies from which column the value in the value column comes from.

Comment: OK thank you very much. Bests

Answer (score 1):

```
writeLines("word;Positive-Polarity;Negative-Polarity
un dos;0;0
abaque;0;0
abandonner;0;1
abandonné;0;1
abandon;0;1
se calmer;0;0","data.csv")

data <- read.csv("data.csv",sep=";")

get_pol <- function(word,type,data)
{
    if(type=="positive") return(data$Positive.Polarity[data$word==word])
    if(type=="negative") return(data$Negative.Polarity[data$word==word])
}

get_pol("abandon","positive",data)

get_pol("abandon","negative",data)
```